# Build XML object on iOS with XCode 4, i.e. with KissXML

Tags: xml, ios

The official NSXML stuff doesn't work on iOS, according to manual (and trial and error). There are some other projects, but most are just XML parsers. But I want to create XML objects.

There is KissXML, but the tutorial on the website only shows how to set up XCode 3 for it. I can't seem to get it to work in XCode 4. There are no positions called "Linking" or "Header search path" in my build settings in XCode 4. I clicked "Add Build Settings" and added "header_search_paths" and "other_ldflags" as seen in the screenshot from XCode 3, but that doesn't work.

Are there any other projects to build XML objects on iOS? Or is there a tutorial on how to get KissXML to work in XCode 4?

Thanks,
MrB

Comment: Oh wow, I'm such an idiot. I clicked "Advanced Build Settings", and there they were! Other Linker Options and Header Head paths..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "getting started"-section of the original source home page contains the best information to get it up and running. Just follow the steps exactly as they're described there and you should be ready to go in 5 minutes.

http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: kissXML have moved over to github https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML/wiki/GettingStarted however I cannot see the images in the area where they tell you how to set this stuff up.